# Manipulating URIs in Python

Tags: python

Consider the following piece of code:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>>
>>> str(Path("gs://a/b/c"))
'gs:/a/b/c'
```

As you can see, the double slash is stripped from the path. I'd like to manipulate this URI, but I would like to preserve the `gs://` prefix with its two slashes.

Question 1: Is `pathlib` the right tool for the job?
Question 2: If not, are there any other tools like it that provide functions like Path's `.stem`, `.name` and `.parent`?

Comment: I can't write a full answer right now, but no, `pathlib` is not the right tool for the job. URIs aren't paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse("gs://a/b/c").geturl()
'gs://a/b/c'
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of `cloudpathlib`?

Its `AnyPath` class can be a drop-in replacement for `pathlib.Path`:

```py
>>> from cloudpathlib import AnyPath as Path
```

```py
>>> local = Path("/home/william/")
>>> type(local)
pathlib.PosixPath
>>> str(local)
'/home/william'
```

```py
>>> cloud = Path("gs://a/b/c")
>>> type(cloud)
cloudpathlib.gs.gspath.GSPath
>>> str(cloud)
'gs://a/b/c'
```

installable with pip (`pip install cloudpathlib[s3,gs,azure]`) or on conda-forge, i think.

disclaimer: i'm not a contributor to this library, and i have no idea how or whether it's maintained